# Firebase fanout data to update specific fields remove other siblings fields

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each user has a conversation node, each time a new conversation has a new message I need to update both conversation nodes for the two user involved in the conversation, I want just to update the "lastMessage" and "tinestamp" fields here is my try:

```
let fanoutObject = [userPath      : dataToUpdate,
                    otherUserPath : dataToUpdate]

K.FirebaseRef.root.updateChildValues(fanoutObject)
```

where the paths for each user is:

```
"/users/{userID}/conversations/{conversationID}"
```

and the dataToUpdate:

```
let dataToUpdate:[String:AnyObject] = ["timestamp"  : message.timestamp,
                                       "lastMessage": message.textBody]
```

Result:

The node conversations for each user is updated **BUT** other fields in the conversation node are removed !

the conversation node fro each user is:

```
  "conversations" : {
    "{conversationID}" : {
      "lastMessage" : "your name ?",
      "seen" : true,
      "timestamp" : 1467849600000,
      "with" : {
        "country" : "US",
        "firstName" : "John",
        "profileImage" : "https://..."
      }
    }
  }
```

*note that the node **conversations** is inside a node **user** which is an element inside the root node **users***

and after update it's :

```
  "conversations" : {
    "{conversationID}" : {
      "lastMessage" : "your name ?",
      "timestamp" : 1467849600000,
    }
  }
```

but I was expecting just to update the two values and keep others ?

According to docs my code should works:

> `updateChildValues`   Update some of the keys for a defined path without
>   replacing all of the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit hard to parse your code, but most likely it's the behavior of `updateChildValues()` that is confusing you.

When you call `updateChildValues()`, the Firebase server will loop over the object that you pass in. For each path in there, it will replace the entire value at that path with the value from that you passed in.

So if your current JSON is:

```
{
  "Users": {
    "uidForUser1": {
      "name": "iOSGeek",
      "id": 2305342
    },
    "uidForUser2": {
      "name": "Frank van Puffelen",
      "id": 209103
    }
}
```

And the update is (in JSON format, the lingua franca of the Firebase Database):

```
{
  "users/uidForUser2/name": "puf",
  "users/uidForUser1/name": "My actual name"
}
```

Your resultant JSON will be:

```
{
  "Users": {
    "uidForUser1": {
      "name": "My actual name",
      "id": 2305342
    },
    "uidForUser2": {
      "name": "puf",
      "id": 209103
    }
}
```

But if you send the following update:

```
{
  "users/uidForUser1": {
    "name": "My actual name"
  },
  "users/uidForUser2": {
    "name": "puf"
  }
}
```

The resulting JSON will be:

```
{
  "Users": {
    "uidForUser1": {
      "name": "My actual name"
    },
    "uidForUser2": {
      "name": "puf"
    }
}
```

**Update**

To update two fields in the same object, but leave the other fields unmodified:

```
{
  "path/to/object/field1": "new value",
  "path/to/object/field2": "new value2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that make sense, but is there a way to update  two fields with the same update in a nodes without erasing other siblings fields, let's say I want to update both name and id and we suppose there is other fields like age, how to just update the id and name with the same call ?

Comment: I added an example of that too.

Comment: Thank you, but that's sad that we can't just pass a dictionary to the the root object and tell it to just replace the values of child fields that exist in the dictionary and leave other siblings fields untouched. because with your approach I need to generate a path for each field, what if I will have 5 users and 3 fields = 15 path to generate ...

Comment: This is indeed a common source of confusion for developers new to multi-location updates. The reason it works this way is that we had to keep the API backwards compatible with the previous implementation. In my experience generating the paths is simple enough, but the confusion this causes is indeed unfortunate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen,  the official Docs do seem inaccurate to me.   A simple change of wording, or example (such as provided here) about how to properly use updateChildValues to set multiple values, while leaving others untouched,  would save many people much time!  (and perhaps data!)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can update the `lastMessage` and `timeStamp` data by replacing the old values by providing full path :

```
let lastMessagePath = "/users/{userID}/conversations/{conversationID}/lastMessage"
let lastTimeStampPath = "/users/{userID}/conversations/{conversationID}/timestamp"

K.FirebaseRef.child(lastMessagePath).setValue(message.timestamp)
K.FirebaseRef.child(lastTimeStampPath).setValue(message.textBody)
```

Comment: thank you, but I thought that there is a batch update for a specific node, because with your approach I will have to update 4 nodes, and if I will update 3 fields for 5 users I will have to create 15 reference...

Comment: according to the  [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#update_specific_fields) , it should work, but it updates the values and remove the siblings fields, it's treated as a `setValue` not an update !

Comment: I am struggling with this inconsistent behaviour.  

```db.ref('myPathToObject').update({prop1: '...'})```

updates the object as expected.
However this:

```const updates = {}
updates['myPathToObject'] = {prop1: '...'}
db.ref().update(updates)```

completely overwrites the object.
  
Is there a way to achieve fan outs without having to write updates for every property separately?